# Why Display on IE not same on other browser (EG: chrome , opera) [CSS ZOOM]?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, zooming

Why Display on IE not same on other browser (EG: chrome , opera) [CSS ZOOM] ?

https://jsfiddle.net/n11b7pw6/

```
<html>
    <body style="zoom: 0.1;">
        <img src ="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/3d/df/34/3ddf340436cc77dc9c468505be1ad123.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

<kbd>[image: IE - screen dump]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Chrome - screen dump]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Opera - screen dump]</kbd>

How to change page height on IE for remove scrollbar ? (Do not use `overflow: hidden;`)

REMARK : IE still zoom our only image not zoom out all of page like other browser.

Comment: `zoom` is a IE relic, use `transform: scale(0.1)` instead

Comment: @LGSon - Still show scrollbar on IE.

Comment: I see that, might be an IE bug.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going with your `zoom` in IE, but it's worth noting that:

- `zoom` doesn't work in Firefox (see the [compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom))
- Very few people use Opera. The key browsers to test are IE (various versions), Edge, Chrome, FF, and Safari
- the standard way to "zoom" is to use `transform: scale()`

Looks like what you want to do is make the image the full height of the window? To do that, you'd do:

```css
/* CSS */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML (body tag can be left out in stacksnippets, and also in jsfiddle -->

<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/3d/df/34/3ddf340436cc77dc9c468505be1ad123.jpg" />
```

Comment: I have to solve this issue by using Zoom / transform CSS.

Comment: That sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you